# Angular2-moment, format to hours and minutes

Tags: angular, angular2-moment

I am trying to parse an object by key and modify one of the fields from seconds to Hours + minutes.

```
tableData[key].forEach(weekday => {
        mappedObject[weekday.day] = weekday.spent;
      });
```

I've imported moment

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Moment } from 'moment';
```

I've tried

```
tableData[key].forEach(weekday => {
        mappedObject[weekday.day] = moment.duration(weekday.spent,"seconds").format("h [hrs], m [min]");
      });
```

But I get Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Duration'.

What do i have to do to make it work ?

Forgot to mention: I am not allowed to install other external dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
let duration = moment.duration(500, "seconds");
alert(`${duration.hours()} hours ${duration.minutes()} minutes `);
```